# Send hotkey to minimized chrome window

Tags: autohotkey, minimized

I need an autohotkey script that can send alt+backspace to a minimized chrome window (without maximizing it).

Basically, I have [a web player app](http://player.highstrike.org/) I've made and on the player window which opens in a smaller window, you can press alt+backspace and it will mute and unmute while the window has focus. (javascript events)

Active Window Info says this:

```
>>>>( TitleMatchMode=slow Visible Text )<<<<
player.highstrike.org/play/
```

I would like script to work only for that url.
I have tried to send cmds to that window but to no avail, can someone please help me? I'd really apreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code i was looking for was

```
SetTitleMatchMode, Slow
Return

$!BS::
KeyWait, BS
ControlSend,Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1,!{Backspace},,player.highstrike.org/play/
Return
```